# Html Emails - Outlook 2010 - Table Align Issue

Tags: html-email, mailchimp, outlook-2010

I have two tables aligned left at 30% each so that when it goes responsive the change to 100% and stack underneath each other.

Problem is as per the screenshot below the second one has a gap at the top and i have no idea why?

My snippet of code is here

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="fullWidth" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30%" class="tableFullWidth">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="topTen">                                                                                                        <p><span>1</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>2</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>3</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>4</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>5</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                                                                <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30%" class="tableFullWidth">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td valign="top" class="topTen">
                                                                            <p><span>6</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>7</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>8</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>9</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                            <p><span>10</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
                                                                            <hr>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
```

[Outlook 2010 - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp7tE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like the same code from the screenshots, background colors are missing and fonts as well. Either way I think you need a ghost column between the tables to align, try the code below:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="fullWidth" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30%" class="tableFullWidth">
                <tr>
<td valign="top" class="topTen">                                                                                                         <p><span>6</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>7</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>8</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>9</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>10</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
<![endif]-->

 <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30%" class="tableFullWidth">
  <tr>
   <td valign="top" class="topTen">
    <p><span>6</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>7</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>8</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>9</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
    <p><span>10</span> FIRST AND LAST NAME</p>
    <hr>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can change the width of the ghost column if you need to. let me know how you go.